# Promote InfoPath fields to columns in the form Library using feature

Tags: infopath

I understand that I can do this easily using the InfoPath Designer. However, I need to deploy the InfoPath form using a feature.

Once the feature is activated, the InfoPath form is shown as a content type. My question is how can I promote InfoPath fields to columns in the form library using code in feature deployment?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to. SharePoint detects the promoted fields in the form automatically and makes them available in the library via the content type.

They are a special type of field that doesn't store any information itself and instead displays form values from the XPath queries associated with each field.